# Java code OK in AIX 3.5, fails in RHEL 7.5: It makes corrupt DOC, DOCX, XLS, XLSX files but good HTML files

Tags: rhel, java, aix

We have a Java process (see below) to generate DOC, DOCX, XLS, XLSX, and HTML and save it to our Linux PCs. It ran well in our old AIX 3.5 machine; but in our new RHEL 7.5 machine, Microsoft proprietary document formats (DOCX, DOC, XLSX, and XLS) it outputs are corrupt. HTML files are not corrupt.

I have downloaded the output files into a Windows PC and try to open them; Exception errors say the DOC/DOCX/XLS/XSLX files are corrupt and cannot be opened.

The Java code works well in the old Linux PC. I am assuming there might some libraries or software we need to install in the new PC.

Below is my java code (Process to generate the file)

int BUFFER_SIZE=1024*256;

```
           int bytesRead=0;
           Resultset rs=obj.resultSet();
           DocumentClass = new DocumentClass();
           ByteArrayOutputStream baos  = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
           byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
           BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(rs.getBinaryStream(1));

           try
           {
                bytesRead = bis.read(buffer,0,BUFFER_SIZE);
                while (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                   baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                   buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                   bytesRead = bis.read(buffer,0,BUFFER_SIZE);
                }
           }
          catch (IOException io ) 
           {
             System.out.println(io.getMessage());
           } 

           DocumentClass.setFileBody(baos);
           BufferedWriter CreateDoc = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/usr/Test.docx"));
            CreateDoc.write(DocumentClass.getFileBody().toString());
            CreateDoc.close();
```

Comment: it affect only kind of Microsoft proprietary document format (like Docx,doc, XLSX and XLS)

Comment: Old PC    :    AIX 3.5

Comment: New PC : Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.5 (Maipo)

Comment: _Sanj_, now that your updates are added to the question, you can click on Delete after each Comment you left that information in, which will leave room for more Comments.

Comment: Are you using the same java version? Maybe you are running a newer java version on RHEL that is not supported? Are the jars/.class files in the classpath the same? Do you have no logfile? What framework/library are you using (CreateDoc)?

Comment: The code you show won't compile, not even if one had access to whatever "DocumentClass" is.